# Can't port forward ports 80 and 443 on tcp but can on udp

Tags: router, port-forwarding

I try to port forward ports 80 and 443 to my CentOS server but router gives me error "Cannot apply this port mapping rule: conflict with local Web GUI service". How can GUI be involved in this and why I can't port forward? I don't know how to solve this. Do you have any idea?

Hardware Version:BCM6362

[udp 80](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JevDG.png)

[tcp 80](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiCy3.png)

Comment: your router is using those ports (the configuration portal you access to configure it) - so you need to use another external port to forward to your CentOS Web Server.

Comment: Decent firmware should allow this, unless the Web GUI service actually listens on the WAN interface on these port(s) (possibly this is the case). Decent firmware should allow you to make it listen only on the (W)LAN interface(s) if you decide you don't need it on WAN (exposing it on WAN is hardly ever a good idea). If you do need it on WAN, decent firmware should allow you to change the port(s) it uses. Note the firmware in your router may or may not be decent in this context.